# Gephi graph layout

Tags: java, layout, graph, jframe, gephi

I am trying to find the optimum (best looking) layout for my graph using following Jframe source code:

```
package org.gephi.toolkit.demos;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.gephi.graph.api.*;
import org.gephi.io.database.drivers.MySQLDriver;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.Container;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.EdgeDefault;
import org.gephi.io.importer.api.ImportController;
import org.gephi.io.importer.plugin.database.EdgeListDatabaseImpl;
import org.gephi.io.importer.plugin.database.ImporterEdgeList;
import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.DefaultProcessor;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.force.StepDisplacement;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.force.yifanHu.YifanHuLayout;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.forceAtlas2.ForceAtlas2;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.forceAtlas2.ForceAtlas2Builder;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.random.Random;
import org.gephi.layout.plugin.random.RandomLayout;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewController;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewModel;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewProperty;
import org.gephi.preview.api.ProcessingTarget;
import org.gephi.preview.api.RenderTarget;
import org.gephi.preview.types.DependantOriginalColor;
import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController;
import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
import org.openide.util.Lookup;
import org.gephi.toolkit.demos.NodeRenderer2;

import processing.core.PApplet;

/**
 * This demo shows basic features from GraphAPI, how to create and query a graph
 * programmatically.
 * 
 * @author Mathieu Bastian
 */
public class TestGraph  {


public void script() {

    ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
    pc.newProject();
    Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

    // import graph from DB
    EdgeListDatabaseImpl db = new EdgeListDatabaseImpl();
    db.setDBName("sn");
    db.setHost("localhost");
    db.setUsername("nirre");
    db.setPasswd("guMli5ic");
    db.setSQLDriver(new MySQLDriver());
    //db.setSQLDriver(new PostgreSQLDriver());
    //db.setSQLDriver(new SQLServerDriver());
    db.setPort(3306);
    db.setNodeQuery("select distinct kp.key as ID, kp.phrase as LABEL from sn.key_phrases1 kp inner join edges_demo e on e.source = kp.key or e.target = kp.key union select distinct kp.key as ID, kp.phrase as LABEL from sn.key_phrases1 kp inner join edges_demo e on e.source = kp.key or e.target = kp.key");
    db.setEdgeQuery("select * from edges_demo");
    ImporterEdgeList edgeListImporter = new ImporterEdgeList();
    ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);
    Container container = importController.importDatabase(db, edgeListImporter);
    container.setAllowAutoNode(false);      //Don't create missing nodes
    container.getLoader().setEdgeDefault(EdgeDefault.UNDIRECTED);   //Force UNDIRECTED

    importController.process(container, new DefaultProcessor(), workspace);
    GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getModel();

    /*RandomLayout layout = new RandomLayout(new Random(),1500);
    layout.setGraphModel(graphModel);
    layout.initAlgo();
    layout.goAlgo();
    layout.endAlgo();
    ForceAtlas2Builder layout_fa2_builder = new ForceAtlas2Builder();
    ForceAtlas2 layout_fa2 = new ForceAtlas2(layout_fa2_builder);
    layout_fa2.setGraphModel(graphModel);
    layout_fa2.resetPropertiesValues();
    layout_fa2.initAlgo();
    layout_fa2.goAlgo();
    layout_fa2.endAlgo();*/
    YifanHuLayout layout_yifan = new YifanHuLayout(null, new StepDisplacement(1f));
    layout_yifan.setGraphModel(graphModel);
    layout_yifan.resetPropertiesValues();
    layout_yifan.initAlgo();
    layout_yifan.goAlgo();
    layout_yifan.endAlgo();
    //Preview configuration
    PreviewController previewController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PreviewController.class);
    PreviewModel previewModel = previewController.getModel();

    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.SHOW_NODE_LABELS, Boolean.TRUE);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.NODE_LABEL_COLOR, new DependantOriginalColor(Color.WHITE));
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_CURVED, Boolean.FALSE);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_OPACITY, 50);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_RADIUS, 10f);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.BLACK);
    //previewController.refreshPreview();

    NodeRenderer2 nr2 = new NodeRenderer2();
    MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
    nr2.needsPreviewMouseListener(ml);
    //New Processing target, get the PApplet

    ProcessingTarget target = (ProcessingTarget) previewController.getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.PROCESSING_TARGET);
    PApplet applet = target.getApplet();
    applet.init();

    //Refresh the preview and reset the zoom


    previewController.render(target);
    previewController.refreshPreview();
      //Add the applet to a JFrame and display--------------------------------------
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Preview");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    target.refresh();
    target.resetZoom();

    /*ProcessingTarget target = (ProcessingTarget) previewController.getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.PROCESSING_TARGET);
    PApplet applet = target.getApplet();
    applet.init();
    //Refresh the preview and reset the zoom
    previewController.render(target);
    target.refresh();
    target.resetZoom();*/

    //Add the applet to a JFrame and display
    /*JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Preview");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);*/
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestGraph previewJFrame = new TestGraph();
    previewJFrame.script();
    }
}
```

however, different layouts (Random Layout, ForceAtlas 2 and Yifan Hu) yield the same graph but randomly drawn. The graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a fairly long time since this question was posted and hopefully you aren't still looking for a solution, but if you are:

You need to surround the layout.goAlgo() method inside a for loop to preform the steps that are needed to place the nodes in place.  You can experiment with the number of iterations needed to get the preferred layout you like.

```
layout_yifan.resetPropertiesValues();<br>
layout_yifan.initAlgo();

    int iterations = Math.pow(numberOfNodes, 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations && layout.canAlgo(); i++) {
        layout_yifan.goAlgo();
    }

    layout.endAlgo();
```